# Wordpress Plugin Options Page Search

Tags: php, search, wordpress

I am building a Wordpress plugin and would like to add a post search field in my options page. I attempted to just add the standard WP search form using `<input type="text" name="s" id="searchform">` but when I click "Submit" I am redirected to the 'General' settings page. How can I implement a search form in my plugin options page and have it return a list of posts to the same page? I'd like to do this without AJAX if possible. The post list markup is quite complicated and it wouldn't be ideal to have to implement it with JS.

I also attempted to copy the search form HTML on the 'Posts' page. That results in the same issue -- being redirected to the 'General' settings page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to use AJAX for this, but I ended up having to. The solution I came up with is to use AJAX to generate a 'redirect' URL and append query arguments using `add_query_arg()` then return the URL with the query parameters and use `window.location.href` to redirect the user. The page is redirected with the query arguments appended and then on page load `WP_Query();` is ran with the `s=` parameter containing the query parameters.

Probably not the most efficient way, or even the proper way, but it gets the job done. If anyone has another solution, I'd love to hear it.

Example PHP Function:

```
public function user_redirect_by_search() {
    $search_arr = array();

    parse_str($_POST['search_data'], $search_arr);

    $return = array();
    $post_type_arr = array();
    $post_type_count = 0;
    foreach($search_arr['post_type'] as $post_type) {
        $post_type_count++; 
        $post_type_arr[$post_type_count] = $post_type;
    }

    $redirect_url = add_query_arg( array('post_type' => implode(",", $post_type_arr), 'keywords' => $search_arr['s']),  $search_arr['page_url']);

    $return['status'] = 1;
    $return['redirect_url'] = $redirect_url;

    echo json_encode($return);
    die();
}
```

And then the jQuery:

```
// Post keyword search
    jQuery('#searchform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var search_data = jQuery(this).serialize();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxurl,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {"action": "user_search", search_data},
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.status == 1) {
                    window.location.href = data.redirect_url;
                    //console.log(data);
                } else {
                    alert("Oops, an error occurred. Please try again or contact the plugin developer.");
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

**Please note the above code is NOT put into production use, it was just written/modified to show an example solution to the question at hand.**

Answer (score 0):

The input text box has to be inclosed within a form. Here is a default html5 form. Just replace your code with this and then fix the styles.

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?></span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search …', 'placeholder' ) ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?>" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ) ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't exactly help. Obviously the form has to be enclosed in a form element, and using `home_url()` in the action redirects me to the frontend of the site. As stated in the question, I need to stay in the dashboard on the same options page the form was submitted from.

Comment: Are you looking to implement the search feature inside the admin panel (options page)?